# How can I attach a listener to multiple radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="P_1" value="1">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="P_1" value="2">No</input>

<input type="radio" name="P_2" value="1">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="P_2" value="2">No</input>

<input type="radio" name="P_3" value="1">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="P_3" value="2">No</input>
```

I am trying to add a listener to each of these radio buttons so that I will be notified when they change. I am doing something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            $("input[name='P_" + i + "']").live('change', function () {
                doProcessing("P_" + i, $("input[name='P_" + i + "']:checked").val());
            });
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. It calls `doProcessing` with `i` set to 4 because that is the value of `i` at the end of the for loop. What is the correct way of adding an event handler in my case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('input:radio').on('change', function(){
    //access value of changed radio group with $(this).val()
});
```

Or, if you're using < jQuery 1.7

```
$('input:radio').live('change', function(){
    //do stuff with $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why he didn't do it this way also. OP, can you provide some feedback on why you are creating separate `live` calls when they all call the same function? Joe's solution seems much simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Just dumb of me! Thank you so much for this approach. Saved me today :)

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad I could help.

Comment: the `on` equivalent to `live` is `$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function...);`

Answer (score 2):

As with any asynchronous iterative value, you need to close over the value in the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(i){
        ...your code here...
    }(i));
}
```

By the time the event handler is called, the value of the `i` variable will have reached its maximum value (in this case `3`).

An alternative means of passing data to each handler, would be to use the `data` parameter of the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $(...selector...).on('change', null, {i:i}, function (e) {
        //access the i value with: e.data.i
    });
}
```

---

It would probably be better to simply check for the right value within the handler, and use a class to attach the event:

```
$(document).on('change', '.someClass', function (e) {
    var i,
        $this;
    $this = $(this);
    i = $(this).attr('name').substr(2);
    i = parseInt(i, 10);
    ...your code here...
});
```

If you can't change the markup, then you can use `'[name^="P_"]'` in place of `'.someClass'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a closure that will remember the index value on each step. Here is one of the many possible ways to do that:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   $("input[name='P_" + i + "']").live('change', createListener(i));
}

function createListener(index) {
    return function() {
        doProcessing("P_" + index, $("input[name='P_" + index + "']:checked").val());
    }
}
```