# jQuery Radio Button Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I've looked here and elsewhere on how to execute a function using jQuery when I click a radio button. I'm able to make the example code work isolated, like in CodePen, but it won't work when integrated into my project.

I'm not using straight radio buttons, but bootstrap-ified buttons. Relevant part of the form ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" id="floors-div">
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="1" value="1" autocomplete="off">1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="2" value="2" autocomplete="off">2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="3" value="3" autocomplete="off">3</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="4" value="4" autocomplete="off">4</label>
</div>
```

I'm able to get an action when the buttons are clicked by using:

```
$("input[name='floors']").parent().click(function() {
...snip...
var buttonVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='floors']:checked").val();
```

But the value is wrong. It returns the value of the previously selected button instead of the current one. If I just do something like:

```
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
...snip...
```

Nothing happens upon clicking the buttons.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I've narrowed down what's causing the problem with your help. Turns out the main difference between the CodePen that I did and production is the inclusion of Bootstrap's JS. Apparently they're overriding something that's messing with the `.change` method. Issue reproduced in CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/RossIV/pen/NqJOMZ).

Edit 2: If it matters, all of my JS is inside `$(document).ready(function(){` as well.

Comment: Your listener is attached to parent .click(), prob an issue of timing, and poor form in my mind - try attaching to radios themselves instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167395/how-can-i-attach-a-listener-to-multiple-radio-buttons

Comment: jQuery `change` event works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tyu294vt/2/

Comment: have you loaded jquery? change event is working perfectly.

Comment: @DanielBrose Just tried that - doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Comment: @WisdmLabs Yep - I have loaded it. I have other jQuery working on the page just fine.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes, I mentioned that in my post. The .change() method works fine in isolation. I duplicated mine on CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/RossIV/pen/XbGJRL).

Comment: In your codepen its showing correct value ie. selected value

Comment: @Ross When you integrate it into your project - are there any errors \ warnings in console?

Comment: Nope, Yeldar. Nothing of the sort.

Comment: @Ross What if you open a page, open a console and write `$("input[name='floors']")`? Are there any items?

Comment: It shows all of the radio buttons as it should. That's the really strange thing. There's no reason why these *aren't* working.

Comment: @Ross Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing your code on codepen ,I sorted out your problem & found that your code is correct, actually the problem was whenever you click on the button,you don't actually clicks on the radio button rather you click on the 'label'. Whenever I remove the label tag your code perfectly works. here is the image.

.[image]

But I solved your problem by this code :) You can check demo.
Also edited your codepen -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJozaQ

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $("label.floorNum").on("click",function()
  { 

          alert($(this).find('input').val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label for="housingArea">Area</label>
            <select id="housingArea" class="form-control">
                <option value="" style="display:none" selected></option>
                <option value="north">North</option>
                <option value="south">South</option>
                <option value="east">East</option>
                <option value="west">West</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="building">Building</label>
            <select id="building" class="form-control">
                <option value="" style="display:none" selected></option>
                <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <!--Fill with info from DB -->
            <label for="floorNum">Floor</label>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
                <label class="btn btn-default floorNum">
                    <input type="radio" name="floorNum" value="1" autocomplete="off">1
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default floorNum">
                    <input type="radio" name="floorNum" value="2" autocomplete="off">2
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default floorNum">
                    <input type="radio" name="floorNum" value="3" autocomplete="off">3
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="roomNum">Room Number</label>
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="101" autocomplete="off">101
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-danger">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="102" autocomplete="off">102
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="103" autocomplete="off">103
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-success">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="104" autocomplete="off">104
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-warning">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="105" autocomplete="off">105
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="106" autocomplete="off">106
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="107" autocomplete="off">107
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="roomNum" id="108" autocomplete="off">108
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YAY! Yours worked perfectly! You have no idea how awesome this is - thank you SO much!

Answer (score 4):

Try like this using [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#using-the-triggering-element).

```
 $("#floors-div").on("change", "input[name='floors']", function () {
        //code snippets
 });
```

Or

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name='floors']", function () {
        //code snippets
 });
```

Comment: Neither worked.  Weird thing is that I did something similar [here](http://codepen.io/RossIV/pen/OVqBwd) and it did work. I even included the Bootstrap JS.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.change` method instead of `.click`

```
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
    var buttonVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='floors']:checked").val();
    alert(buttonVal);
})
```

**OR**

```
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
    var buttonVal = $(this).val();
    alert(buttonVal);
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxe9ue97/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `change()` event works fine for me with your code:

```js
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
    var val = $("input[type='radio'][name='floors']:checked").val();
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" id="floors-div">
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="1" value="1" autocomplete="off">1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="2" value="2" autocomplete="off">2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="3" value="3" autocomplete="off">3 
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" name="floors-label">
        <input type="radio" name="floors" id="4" value="4" autocomplete="off">4
    </label>
</div>
```

Probably, the problem is somewhere else but not at this part of code.

By the way, it is definitely better to use `this.value` instead of such a big selector.
It is easier, it is DOM property (vanilla JS), it is faster and readable:

```
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding your on click event after the document has loaded with this call:

```
$("input[name='floors']").on("click",function(e)
{
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Just tested this and clicking the various button returns the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can just try this hope this will work for you

```js
$("#floors-div input:radio[name='floors']").on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

for getting value you need to just use **$(this).val();** in my code.

Comment: No luck with this. Clarification: Nothing happens. It's not that I don't get the value...nothing shows up in the console at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change()` event. `this` point to current element

```
$("input[name='floors']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();// this
    alert(val);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g38042h/)